# Is array_push() as efficient as creating an array with elements inside it

Tags: php, performance

I found some old code that i created a while back when I first started programming, I was pushing 50+ elements into an array rather then creating them inside the array at the start.

Am i effecting performance when I push multiple elements into my array rather then just create the array containing the elements at the start.

Comment: you really shouldn't worry about such things, that's php. choose what has more sense for you.

Comment: No idea of the performance, but WHY would you not create the array with all it's values from the start if possible?

Comment: I found some old code that i created a while back when I first started programming, I was pushing 50+ elements into an array rather then creating them inside the array at the start.

Comment: No, of course it's fractionally less efficient, as each array_push introduces an overhead of calling a function, but we're talking about 50 values here, do it however you deem necessary, you won't win or lose much performance-wise either way.

Comment: The difference surely exists (also note that php recommend the use of `[]` syntax instead of `push` while adding one only element), but I don't think that you can have any perceptible issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array_push()` is slower than `$array[]`. In the [PHP docs](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php#116943) somebody did a good performance test.

I guess because of the internal implementation. Probably it will create a new array each time and/or allocate new memory, which makes it more slower. But we are talking about hundreds or thousands of records. Anything less doesn't have a noticeable impact on performance.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you use array_push() to add one element to the array it's better to use $array[] = because in that way there is no overhead of calling a function.

   2. array_push() will raise a warning if the first argument is not an array. This differs from the $var[] behaviour where a new array is created.

plz check link

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php